# About the usage of "decelerate"

Tags: word-choice

> 1. China’s **economic growth decelerated** in the fourth quarter of 2018.
> 2. China’s **economy decelerated** in the fourth quarter of 2018.

Which one to choose when the meaning is that the Chinese economy grew at a slower pace?

Comment: The growth decelerated (reduced its speed). It **grew** (not growed) at a slower pace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slightly more about the economic terminology than the English language, but let's run with it.

Acceleration is the rate at which something is changing speed. Deceleration is negative acceleration. So, the economy is growing at a certain speed. If that speed is going up, the growth is getting bigger each year - the growth is accelerating. If that speed is going down, the growth is decelerating. Thus, it is reasonably unambiguous to people who are used to this terminology to say the economic growth decelerated if the growth figure one year is lower than for the last (or for a quarter, or so on, though with quarters you need to be clear if you are comparing year-on-year by quarter, or quarter-on-quarter).

However, it is quite common to talk about economies accelerating or decelerating, as well. This usually means the same thing, but is less precise and may lead to misunderstandings even among people who are reasonably used to the terminology of economics as discussed in politics and the media.

If people aren't used to that terminology at all, however, they may be confused by either. If you want to be completely unambiguous, you would say that the economic growth in the quarter was lower than whatever-you-are-comparing-it-to (usually the same quarter the previous year, sometimes to the last quarter before it). If you want to be even more clear, you could say that the GDP grew less in that quarter than whatever you are comparing it to.